# POST a Complex JSON using Javax-RS & Java Persistence & RESTful

Tags: java, json, rest, persistence

I would like to apologize in advanced if this is a duplicate, however, I've been looking around for the last 2 days and have not found anything that solves my problem.

I have created a web service to which I would like to POST  a JSON object. My issue is the following:

Let's say I have three objects.

```
ObjectA:{
"name":"",
"address":"",
"id":""
}

ObjectB:{
"id:"",
"name":"",
"objectA":{ [ObjectA]}
}

ObjectC:{
"id:"",
"name":"",
"objectA":{},
"objectB":{}
}
```

As you can see,ObjectC references ObjectA and ObjectB, which also references ObjectA. When inserting a new ObjectC, ObjectC.objectA should be the same as ObjectC.objectB.objectA.

**The POST is consumed by the following method:**

```
@POST
@Override
@Consumes({"application/xml", "application/json"})
public void create(ObjectC entity) {        
            super.create(entity);
}
```

**The classes look like this:** (plus the getters and setters)

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "object_a")
public class ObjectA{

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @Column(name = "id")
    private Integer id;

    @NotNull
    @Column(name = "u_name")
    private String uName;

    @Column(name = "address")    
    private String address;
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "object_b")
public class ObjectB{

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @Column(name = "id")
    private Integer id;

    @Column(name = "name")
    private String name;

    @JoinColumn(name = "object_a", referencedColumnName = "id")
    @ManyToOne(optional = false, cascade = CascadeType.PERSIST)
    @Valid
    private ObjectA objectA;
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "object_c")
public class ObjectC{

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Basic(optional = false)
    @Column(name = "id")
    private Integer id;

    @Column(name = "name")
    private String name;

    @JoinColumn(name = "object_a", referencedColumnName = "id")
    @ManyToOne(optional = false, cascade = CascadeType.PERSIST)
    @Valid
    private ObjectA objectA;

    @JoinColumn(name = "object_b", referencedColumnName = "id")
    @ManyToOne(optional = false, cascade = CascadeType.PERSIST)
    @Valid
    private ObjectB objectB;

}
```

Note: I am able to POST an ObjectA, and an ObjectB without any problem.

**PROBLEM**
The problem is that ObjectC.objectA and ObjectC.objectB.objectA are being inserted (or attempted to) as different values, which in throws an exception because ObjectA.uName is unique. If this wasn't the case, two new ObjectA's would have been created.

I was able to solve this problem in Hibernate, by doing something like the following:

```
ObjectA a = new ObjectA();
ObjectB b = new ObjectB();
ObjectC c = new ObjectC();

b.setObjectA(a);
c.setObjectA(a);
c.setObjectB(b);

session.beginTransaction();
session.save(a);
session.save(b);
session.save(c);
session.getTransaction().commit();
```

How can I go about this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone out there who might come across this issue, I have found the solution.

I did it in a very similar way to what I did in hibernate (see above).

I edited the **`create`** method I posted above, to this:

```
@POST
@Override
@Consumes({"application/xml", "application/json"})
public void create(ObjectC entity) {

    if(entity.getObjectA().getId()==null){//If objectA doesn't have an ID, it must be new

            entity.getObjectB().setObjectA(entity.getObjectA());
            em.persist(entity.getObjectA());
            em.persist(entity.getObjectB());
            em.persist(entity);     


    }else{//Otherwise, everything may be inserted at once.
        super.create(entity);        
    }

}
```

By the way, the `super.create(entity)` method contains the following:

```
public void create(T entity){            
        getEntityManager().persist(entity);       

}
```